# Il n’est pas jusqu’à l’Antarctique qui ne soit pollué

Tags: sens, prépositions, négation, formulation, registre-soutenu

According to *Oxford-Hachette* French dictionary, this is translated as ‘even the Antarctic is polluted’ and I can’t wrap my head around this translation.

I can’t figure out the construction used which makes it translate the way it is.

> Il n’est pas jusqu’à l’Antarctique qui ne soit pollué.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a formal and somewhat literary construction. First of all, *[il est](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre)* (impersonal) for *il y a* (there is) is a formal construction. Then you have this literary expression "*il n'y a pas jusqu'à/il n'est pas [jusqu'à](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jusque)* + substantif et proposition relative au subjonctif avec *ne*", "marquant avec insistance le point de référence limite" (TLFi) i.e. adding strong emphasis to the reference point limit. Word for word you end up with something along the lines of "there isn't (even) up to the Antarctic that isn't polluted". In so many words, "even the Antarctic is polluted", just fancier with the emphasis on this (remote) location. This construction with the double *ne* negation element also takes the subjunctive (*soit*), setting it further apart from the casual. See also [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/il-ny-avait-pas-jusqu%C3%A0-x-qui-ne-fasse-y.3010943/) for further details. This construction is beautiful...

---

> [...] Un arrangement en train de se désagréger, mais c'est là, avec
> évidence, toute l'explication de *la Ronde de nuit*. Toute la
> composition d'avant en arrière est faite sur le principe d'un
> mouvement de plus en plus accéléré, comme d'un talus de sable qui
> s'écroule. Les deux personnages du premier plan sont en marche, ceux
> de la seconde ligne ont déjà mis le pied en avant, ceux du fond ne
> font encore que mesurer du regard le chemin à parcourir dont le
> philosophe latéral indique de la main la direction, mais, déjà, comme
> des grains plus légers qui se détachent, à droite le gamin à la poire
> à poudre et le petit chien à gauche se sont mis au galop. La pique
> dans la main du capitaine solaire joue le même rôle que tout à l'heure
> le vin dans le verre (représentant la puissance d'oscillation) et la
> pelure de citron, elle sert pour ainsi dire de balancier et de
> régulateur latent à ce mouvement qui anime l'ensemble. Les trois
> arquebusiers rouges sur la seconde ligne, l'un qui charge son arme,
> l'autre comme tapi et embusqué derrière son chef, c'est l'ébranlement
> vers une aventure dont l'on voit bien qu'elle comporte des dangers.
> Mais comment résister à l'imagination, cette fée lumineuse, cette
> pénétrante messagère de l'au-delà, qui porte à la ceinture, en tant
> que lettres de créance, une colombe ? Et déjà devant elle son acolyte
> masqué s'est frayé un passage vers l'intérieur à travers le groupe des
> chevaliers de l'aventure dont, au-dessus de lui un étincelant
> gentilhomme, couleur de mer, arbore fièrement le drapeau rayé de rouge
> et de noir. Mais, au fond, débouchant parmi de fortes architectures
> d'un sombre porche, l'arrière-garde immobile par-dessus la tête de ses
> compagnons qui de degré en degré ont fait le pas en avant, envisage et
> mesure l'avenir : c'est pour y toucher plus tôt sans doute qu'ils se
> sont munis de ces longues piques ! On voit briller des casques, un
> hausse-col, une écharpe, un corset de soie. **Il n'est pas jusqu'à ce
> haut chapeau sur la tête d'un personnage falot qui n'ait l'air d'un
> phare, d'une tour d'observation**. Les spectateurs bientôt, on sent
> qu'ils vont se transformer en acteurs, ils sont prêts, le tambour
> roule, car cette page empruntée aux plus sombres officines du songe
> est cependant pleine d'un étrange bruit muet : le tambour, l'aboiement
> du petit chien, cette parole sur la lèvre fleurie du capitaine Cock,
> cette conversation d'œil à œil entre les témoins de droite, ce coup de
> fusil et celui, futur, que l'arquebusier de gauche empile
> précautionneusement au fond de son arme. On part ! [...]
>
> [ [Claudel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Claudel), [*L'œil écoute*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C5%93il_%C3%A9coute), [au sujet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotypose) de [*Ronde de nuit*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C5%93il_%C3%A9coute#/media/Fichier:La_Ronde_de_nuit.jpeg) de
> Rembrandt ]

[image]

<sup>[*La Ronde de nuit*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C5%93il_%C3%A9coute#/media/Fichier:La_Ronde_de_nuit.jpeg), de [Rembrandt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt), reproduction par Khâgneux, sur [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:La_Ronde_de_nuit.jpeg), cc by-SA 4.0</sup>

Comment: Personnellement je trouve cette construction désagréable tant qu'un antécédent n'est pas explicitement produit  pour « qui ».

Answer (score 0):

This construction is explained in this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44591/17649) for the most of what you have to understand; it is also important to understand clearly something more: there is in this construction no antecedent for the pronoun "qui", and when you read you are left seeking for it without hope of finding it. This means that a modification of your sentence as follows (a sensible antecedent has been inserted) results in a  sentence that is also  correct  as well as  of a pleasanter turn (it might be so from your perspective, it is from mine).

- il n’est pas de région du globe, jusqu’à l’Antarctique, qui ne soit polluée

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Non, cela semble être le cas parce que vous avez l'impression que j'aurais une dent contre vous ; rendez vous compte que je serais en train de définir mon choix en fonction d'une attitude hautement subjective ; c'est aberrant, je ne me rappellerais même pas finalement de que je reprocherais à la langue ; non, sincèrement, je suis irrité par une fonctionnalité pervertie de cette construction : quand je lis « qui » je ne le lis pas pour rien, il apporte quelque chose à mes « mécanismes » de décodage ;  dans ce tour mon esprit se heurte à un mot dans le vide, que fait « qui » ?

Comment: C'est tout, même l'Antarctique, qui est pollué.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Je sais bien que lorsqu'on utilise une tournure  comme « qu'est-ce que c'est » on ne se pose pas de question sur deux « ce » en redondance et le problème est un peu le même ; mais je ne pense pas que ce soit une raison pour tolérer trop de formes de cette sorte. En passant (ce que je ne pouvait pas mentionner plus haut faute de place) :  je pense que l'utilisation de « jusque » pourrait être idiomatique dans les deux constructions mais un raisonnement net me manque (ce qui suffirait pour parler de tour)  ; sinon, il ne s'agit pas d'un tour, ce qui est probablement le cas.

Comment: @LPH: Ou « Il n’est nulle part jusqu’à l’Antarctique qui ne soit pollué » ?

Comment: @HarryAudus C'est une question assez difficile et vous préfèreriez probablement en avoir un aperçu plus en profondeur que ce qu'un avis sommaire et une simple modification puisse vous apporter ; aussi, vu le manque de place dans les champs de commentaires, je vais devoir vous faire part de ce que je pense utile à ce propos dans la section discussion (chat).